# figure/image not showing up

Tags: graphics

I have the following but the image does not show up for some reason.

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figures/stats_count.png}
    \caption{The number of sentences from each category}
    \label{fig:sent_diagram}
}
\end{figure}
```

I am using following packages:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,total={6in, 9.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\graphicspath{ {Figuras/} }
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was caused by multicol package. Did these to fix:

```
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}
```

Then just replaced "figure" with "Figure":

```
\begin{Figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figures/stats_count.png}
    \captionof{figure}{The number of sentences from each category}
    \label{fig:sent_diagram}
\end{Figure}
```

**EDIT**

The better solution is to use twocolumn option instead of multicol package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
```

Comment: The problem is that a minipage with spaces is a poor substitute of a true float. For the usual two-columns only documents,  the right fix is not  `multicol` with  a custom `Figure` environment and  `\captionof` that need another package, but   just `twocolumn` option in the first line.  Reserve `multicol` and their drawbacks only for more complex layouts. BTW, if you want the images sizes fitting consistently in surrounding text, use some like `width=0.8\linewidth` instead of   `scale=0.5`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I ended up implementing that method, however, the one posted does the job as well.